# Easy configuration for domain:8080 to 80 Tomcat

Tags: apache, tomcat

Is there an easy way to change from domain.com:8080/myapp to domain.com? Any step by step working examples for Tomcat 7?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use Apache Mod_Proxy for this. You use Apache2 as a front-end to your Tomcat instance.

Here is a configuration example:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    ServerName site.domain.com
    Redirect / /tomcat-context/
    ProxyPass /tomcat-context/ http://127.0.0.1:tomcat-port/tomcat-context/
    ProxyPassReverse /tomcat-context/ http://site.domain.com/tomcat-context/
    ProxyPreserveHost On
</VirtualHost>
```

You can find more infos [here](http://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/FAQ/Connectors#Q3).

It may seem a bit hard to grasp at first if you're not an Apache2 expert (I am not), but once you've configured your first frontend, adding more and more tomcat instances behind it is a breeze.

Or if you're lazy, change the connector port from 8080 to 80 in the conf/server.xml file in your tomcat home directory.

Comment: Can i give you my account, and can you do it for me? I have been trying for days.

Comment: Hum no lol And you should not propose such stuff to strangers! But we can try to find what you're doing wrong here.

Comment: changing the connector from 8080 to 80 just like that causes problems.

Comment: What kind of problems ? Do you already have other applications (most likely Apache) listening on this port ?

Comment: I know i should not propose such stuff to strangers, but i am tired and deparate and have not visited my girlfriend in days. She wants to kill me.

Comment: Ahahah it was the same for me for my first attempt, it's really hard to grasp the proxying stuff in Tomcat. Is it for work ? Here is a basic checklist : Are you on linux ? Do you already have Apache2 running well ? Is your tomcat server perfectly running on 8080 ? Do you have root access to your server (problem with port 80 can come from unpriviledged account) ? Do you have Mod_Proxy installed in Apache2 ? Do you understand the idea behind proxying ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48169/discussion-between-pierre-and-ejobity)

Comment: Its not for work. its a personal project. I am really excited about learning. Did alot so far on my own. I am on CentOS 6. I already have Apache 2 running well. It is running well on 8080. I have root access to my server as well. I not sure if i have Mod_Proxy installed. I dont understand the idea behind proxying.

Comment: Awesome help and advise. Excellant Teacher Pieere. :-)